# Expression result unused -wunused-value in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, expression

I'm not sure how to fix this, the error says "expression result unused -wunused-value." How would I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
[self addChild: hero];
    screenWidth/2, screenHeight/10;
```

Comment: The 2nd line doesn't look like a valid ObjC code. Copy/paste error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: if you just want to fix the warning, delete second line

Answer (score 1):

The second line, `screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2` causes two divisions to occur but the results of those division operations are not used.  If you need `screenWidth/2` and `screenHeight/2` for something, you should store the results of the divisions in variables and use them later.  If you *don't* need those values then you should remove the second line and that will eliminate the warning.

The `-wunused-value` part of the warning indicates that you are being warned by the compiler about unused results like this one.  It's possible to disable this warning in your target's build settings in Xcode, but my recommendation is to leave the warning on and resolve the issues it finds.